# How to fix order of citations?

Tags: bibliographies, apacite

Hello currently I am using a separate `.bib` files for citations, however I found something rather odd that for some reason my first citations is the second citation in LaTeX.

[image: As seen here]

```
@techreport{mellor1975mechanics1,
  title={Mechanics of Cutting and Boring: Part {I} Kinematics of Transverse Rotation Machines},
  author={Mellor, Malcolm},
  year={1975},
  volume={Special Report 226},
  institution={Corps of Engineers US Army Cold Regions Research and Engineering Laboratory Hanover New Hampshire}
}
@techreport{mellor1975mechanics2,
  title={Mechanics of Cutting and Boring: Part {II} Kinematics of Axial Rotation Machines},
  author={Mellor, Malcolm},
  volume={76-16},
  year={1975},
  institution={Corps of Engineers US Army Cold Regions Research and Engineering Laboratory Hanover New Hampshire}
}
```

How would I be able to fix this such that Part I is indeed the first citated citation?

Unsure if relevant information but I use this cite command :

```
\newcommand{\citeq}[1]{(\citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1})}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright,a4paper,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[notocbib]{apacite}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}
\subfile{sections/97_Bibliography/Bibliography.tex}

\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Bibliography}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Literature}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bronnen}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

Something like this?

Comment: well sorting depends on the sorting options. So show a small complete example that allows to see which one you are using and to test solutions.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! As Ulrike said, to understand why your exmaple sorts the entries the way it does you'd have to show a minimal working example with bibliography. If you're unsure how to do this, [this guide shows you how](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/172164).

Comment: I had a few tests with your entries and in all the situations I made up I got the expected sorting of `mellor1975mechanics1` first and `mellor1975mechanics2` second. We can only help you if you can share with us how you produce your bibliography. (This is best done in a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) You have tagged your question with `biblatex` and none of the standard styles will produce the output shown in the screenshot. So either you are using a custom style or you don't use `biblatex` at all. The solution will heavily depend on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apacite` sorts by name, year and title. The first time the two entries differ is in the second part of the `title`, namely

```
Part {I} Kinematics ...
```

and

```
Part {II} Kinematics ...
```

if we discard the braces, convert everything to lowercase and remove spaces (which is what `apacite` does for sorting titles) "partii" (`mellor1975mechanics2`) sorts before "partik" (`mellor1975mechanics1`) because *i* comes before *k* in the alphabet.

One way to force the expected sorting would be with `\APACSortNoop`, which is explained in the `apacite` documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{mellor1975mechanics1,
  title       = {Mechanics of Cutting and Boring:
                 Part {\APACSortNoop{01}}{I}
                 Kinematics of Transverse Rotation Machines},
  author      = {Mellor, Malcolm},
  year        = {1975},
  volume      = {Special Report 226},
  institution = {Corps of Engineers, US Army,
                 Cold Regions Research and Engineering Laboratory,
                 Hanover, New Hampshire},
}
@techreport{mellor1975mechanics2,
  title       = {Mechanics of Cutting and Boring:
                 Part {\APACSortNoop{02}}{II}
                 Kinematics of Axial Rotation Machines},
  author      = {Mellor, Malcolm},
  volume      = {76-16},
  year        = {1975},
  institution = {Corps of Engineers, US Army,
                 Cold Regions Research and Engineering Laboratory,
                 Hanover, New Hampshire},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citep{mellor1975mechanics1,mellor1975mechanics2}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Mellor, M. (1975a). Mechanics of cutting and boring: Part I kinematics of transverse rotation machines (Vol. Special Report 226; Tech. Rep.). Corps of Engineers, US Army, Cold Regions Research and Engineering Laboratory, Hanover, New Hampshire.//Mellor, M. (1975b). Mechanics of cutting and boring: Part II kinematics of axial rotation machines (Vol. 76-16; Tech. Rep.). Corps of Engineers, US Army, Cold Regions Research and Engineering Laboratory, Hanover, New Hampshire.]

Note that it is not recommended to load `apacite` and `natbib` in the same document manually. If you want to use `apacite` with `natbib` commands, then let `apacite` load `natbib` for you with `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}`.

---

I would change the entries a bit to make them look like this. In particular I think that `volume` is not the right field here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{mellor1975mechanics1,
  title       = {Mechanics of Cutting and Boring:
                 Part {\APACSortNoop{01}}{I}
                 Kinematics of Transverse Rotation Machines},
  author      = {Mellor, Malcolm},
  year        = {1975},
  type        = {Special Report},
  number      = {226},
  institution = {Corps of Engineers, US Army,
                 Cold Regions Research and Engineering Laboratory},
  address     = {Hanover, New Hampshire},
  url         = {http://hdl.handle.net/11681/11794},
}
@techreport{mellor1975mechanics2,
  title       = {Mechanics of Cutting and Boring:
                 Part {\APACSortNoop{02}}{II}
                 Kinematics of Axial Rotation Machines},
  author      = {Mellor, Malcolm},
  type        = {CRREL Report},
  number      = {76-16},
  year        = {1975},
  institution = {Corps of Engineers, US Army,
                 Cold Regions Research and Engineering Laboratory},
  address     = {Hanover, New Hampshire},
  url         = {http://hdl.handle.net/11681/9538},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citep{mellor1975mechanics1,mellor1975mechanics2}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Mellor, M. (1975a). Mechanics of cutting and boring: Part I kinematics of transverse rotation machines (Special Report No. 226). Hanover, New Hampshire: Corps of Engineers, US Army, Cold Regions Research and Engineering Laboratory. Retrieved from http://hdl.handle.net/11681/11794//Mellor, M. (1975b). Mechanics of cutting and boring: Part II kinematics of axial rotation machines (CRREL Report No. 76-16). Hanover, New Hampshire: Corps of Engineers, US Army, Cold Regions Research and Engineering Laboratory. Retrieved from http://hdl.handle.net/11681/9538]

---

I should mention that at the time of writing `apacite` produces citations and a bibliography according to the 6th edition of the APA manual. The 7th edition of the manual was published in 2019, so `apacite` no longer implements current APA style. The only LaTeX implementation of 7th ed.-APA style citation and bibliography that I am aware of is `biblatex-apa` (version 9.0 from 2019-11-23 or above)

```
\documentclass[american]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{mellor1975mechanics1,
  title       = {Mechanics of Cutting and Boring:
                 Part {I} Kinematics of Transverse Rotation Machines},
  author      = {Mellor, Malcolm},
  year        = {1975},
  type        = {Special Report},
  number      = {226},
  institution = {Corps of Engineers, US Army,
                 Cold Regions Research and Engineering Laboratory},
  location    = {Hanover, New Hampshire},
  url         = {http://hdl.handle.net/11681/11794},
}
@techreport{mellor1975mechanics2,
  title       = {Mechanics of Cutting and Boring:
                 Part {II} Kinematics of Axial Rotation Machines},
  author      = {Mellor, Malcolm},
  type        = {CRREL Report},
  number      = {76-16},
  year        = {1975},
  institution = {Corps of Engineers, US Army,
                 Cold Regions Research and Engineering Laboratory},
  location    = {Hanover, New Hampshire},
  url         = {http://hdl.handle.net/11681/9538},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{mellor1975mechanics1,mellor1975mechanics2}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

In this case no `\APACSortNoop` workaround is needed, but if you find yourself in a similar situation, you could use the `sorttitle` field

```
@techreport{mellor1975mechanics1,
  title       = {Mechanics of Cutting and Boring:
                 Part {I} Kinematics of Transverse Rotation Machines},
  sorttitle   = {Mechanics of Cutting and Boring: Part 01},
  author      = {Mellor, Malcolm},
  year        = {1975},
  type        = {Special Report},
  number      = {226},
  institution = {Corps of Engineers, US Army,
                 Cold Regions Research and Engineering Laboratory},
  location    = {Hanover, New Hampshire},
  url         = {http://hdl.handle.net/11681/11794},
}
@techreport{mellor1975mechanics2,
  title       = {Mechanics of Cutting and Boring:
                 Part {II} Kinematics of Axial Rotation Machines},
  sorttitle   = {Mechanics of Cutting and Boring: Part 02},
  author      = {Mellor, Malcolm},
  type        = {CRREL Report},
  number      = {76-16},
  year        = {1975},
  institution = {Corps of Engineers, US Army,
                 Cold Regions Research and Engineering Laboratory},
  location    = {Hanover, New Hampshire},
  url         = {http://hdl.handle.net/11681/9538},
}
```

Comment: This worked indeed, thank you for you extensive answer